# reverse 2-dimensional array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to reverse 2-dimension array
so if i have

```
    int [,] Y = new int [3,4] {
                               {0, 1, 2, 3} ,  
                               {4, 5, 6, 7} ,  
                               {8, 9, 10, 11}   
};
```

how i can make the reverse of this array to be like

```
                                {3, 7, 11}
                                {2, 6, 10}
                                {1, 5, 9}
                                {0, 4, 8}
```

i just wanna know the logic in any language

Comment: Then why tag so many other languages?

Comment: what is the problem? The logic is to reverse the columns, anything beyond that depends on the language

Comment: And you don't really want to reverse an array. You want to rotate it counter-clockwise. You can figure it out from [this link](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5667482614366208)

Comment: What you are doing is called rotating, not reversing

Comment: thank u 
i add the tags for so many language cause i just wanna to know the logic for any of these language it will be good to me for understanding

Comment: I'm sorry for this misunderstanding cause may English isn't that good

Answer (score 0):

You just have to map the `[i][j]` element of the first array to the `[M-1-j][i]` element of the second array, where `M` is the number of columns.